# Fontspec transparency problems

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I'm using this minimal document to test transparency:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xunicode, xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Color=red,Opacity=0.1,Scale=12]{Helvetica}Test
\end{document}
```

The rendered text is fully opaque when typeset through TeXShop with TeXLive 2011 on a MacOS Lion. Is this a known issue?

Comment: This document simply fails to compile for me. (Seems to require `calc`) (TeXLive 2011, Mac 10.6).  (TeXShop has nothing to do with this, I would assume.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't why, the document is compiling normally for me.

Comment: This is a XeLaTeX problem.  Compiling the same document with LuaLaTeX gets the opacity right.

Comment: You should load xunicode *after* fontspec or it will not setup its definitions correctly. Actually todo it is enough to either load xtlxtra or fontspec. Both will load xunicode at the correct place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `fontspec` manual (p.16):

> Transparency is supported by LuaLaTeX and by XeLaTeX with the `xdv2pdf` driver (Mac OS X only); XeLATeX with the `xdvipdfmx` driver does not support this feature.

TeXShop has an engine for compiling XeLaTeX with the `xdv2pdf` driver.  You can activate it by dragging it from the `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive` folder to the `Engines` folder.  Compiling your document with this driver gives the desired transparency.

I don't think, however, that this driver is actively supported anymore, (the `xdvipdfmx` driver is the default) so it's unclear if using it will affect other things.